# Macro required to cycle through list on sheet 2 and fetch back info from sheet 1

Tags: list, macros, summary

I use this website a lot for complicated excel issues and find the knowledge base to be astounding - thanks :)

Now I have a "hard to explain" excel query I hope somebody can help with - I will explain it the best I can.

I have an excel sheet which I use to enter a stock exchange ticker (eg. VOD.L) into cell B1

The sheet then pulls a mass of information from the internet for me regarding that particular stock.

Because of the complexity & size of each sheet, simply creating 500 of them is not maintainable.

I have a list of 500 share tickers and this is what I would like to do:

- For each entry in Col A of list (stored on sheet 2)
  Place into B1 of sheet 1
- Once the data has been pulled (takes around 2 seconds) - send the data in cell AE200   back to sheet 2 into Col B.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Shaun